# Excel VBA Macro Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to use a VBA macro to copy a webpage (https://weather.gc.ca/warnings/index_e.html) into an excel spreadsheet - all I am looking to copy is the section where there is a table starting with Location, Warning, Watch, Statement

Every time I write something it will copy it over

The first few rows gives me this:

First problem is When it says WindWind warning ... I am looking for it to copy it as it is off the website where it just says "Wind" "Rainfall" "Special Weather" etc ... not the entire thing

The script I am using is as below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.ClearContents
    With xml
        .Open "GET", "https://weather.gc.ca/warnings/index_e.html", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Environment Canada's [web API](https://www.canada.ca/en/environment-climate-change/services/weather-general-tools-resources/weather-tools-specialized-data/free-service.html) instead of scraping a results page?

Comment: Check HTML content. You need remove `<span class="wb-inv">...</span>` nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working for me, however, as stated in the comments consider using the API.

This approach finds the table, copy it the clipboard, then pastes the whole table in one go.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim html        As Object: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim result      As String
    Dim Clip        As Object: Set Clip = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", "https://weather.gc.ca/warnings/index_e.html", False
        .send
        result = .responseText
    End With

    If Len(result) > 0 Then html.body.innerhtml = result

    Clip.SetText html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).outerhtml
    Clip.PutInClipboard

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Cells.ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text"
    End With
End Sub
```